# How can i store this value to database

Tags: laravel, rest, api, laravel-5

I would like to store data to a database by creating a rest api.

Here is the data:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2018-09-17 13:00:20",
        "id": 1,
        "latitude": "11.022992",
        "longitude": "76.9410799",
        "status": "0",
        "updateddate": "2018-09-17 13:00:20"
    },
    { 
        "date": "2018-09-17 13:00:20",
        "id": 1,
        "latitude": "11.022992",
        "longitude": "76.9410799",
        "status": "0",
        "updateddate": "2018-09-17 13:00:20"
    },
    { 
        "date": "2018-09-17 13:00:20",
        "id": 1,
        "latitude": "11.022992",
        "longitude": "76.9410799",
        "status": "0",
        "updateddate": "2018-09-17 13:00:20"
    }
]
```

Please help to create rest api to achieve this.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make One HTML Form for get inputs. Then Copy this in Your files

Controller : Copy in your Controller
About Your id it will be auto increment in your database

```
 public function yourfuncname(Request $request){
    $date= $request->get('date');
    $longitude= $request->get('longitude');
    $latitude= $request->get('latitude');
    $status= $request->get('status'); // Depend On your status if its default 0 then dont make input field for it
    $updateddate= $request->get('updateddate'); // i think you need to find for date

   $Model = new Model_Name;
   $Model->add($date, $latitude , $longitude, $status, $updateddate);
```

Now In your Model :

```
public function add($date, $latitude , $longitude, $status, $updateddate){
\DB::table('employees')->insert([
        'date'=>$date,
        'latitude '=>$latitude,
        'longitude'=>$longitude,
        'status'=>$status,
        'updateddate'=>$updateddate
    ]);
 }
```

This Code Insert your data in Database